# Is this conditional inside a for loop adding time complexity to the function?

Tags: performance, for-loop, conditional-statements, time-complexity, big-o

So, i have this code and i'm triying to get the Big O notation for it

```
const checkWhatElementIsOlder = arrayOfObjects => {
let olderElement = arrayOfObjects[0]; //O(1)

for (let element = 0; element < arrayOfObjects.length; element++) { //O(n)
    if(arrayOfObjects[element].year < olderElement.year){ //O(1) or O(n)??
        olderElement = arrayOfObjects[element];
    }
}

return olderElement;
};
```

but i dont know if the first line inside the loop (the conditional) adds nested complexity to the function, making it go O(n^2) or not since it access to an array's element that is changing every iteration but its value its already defined when readed so i get really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop in your code snippet is `O(N)`, where `N` is the length of the `arrayOfObjects` array.  The check which happens in the `if` statement always happens, for each iteration, regardless.  Whether the `if` block is entered may vary, but both the `if` check and the assignment inside the `if` block are a constant running time operation.

Comment: Oh, so i dont even have to care about what's inside the if statement right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not entirely correct.  If the inside of the `if` statement contained, for example, another loop which were `O(N)`, then the combined order would be `O(N^2)`.  But that's not the case here.